# Should I pass all values if there are many optional parameters in PHP

Tags: php, function

Let take following example.

```
public function do_this($id, $title = NULL, $status = false, $permission = false){

    //Do the task

}
```

According to above function `$title`, `$status` and `$permission` are **optional parameters**.

- If I want to pass just ID, I use `do_this(15);`
- If I want to pass Id and Permission I use  `do_this(15, NULL, false, true);`

So even there are three parameters are optional I had to pass all four parameters when I need to use just one optional parameters.

What I am doing is correct or is there way to pass just id and permission  parameters.

Comment: This is correct, you need to duplicate the state of the existing parameters.

Comment: yeap ... you are doing it correctly ... no other way.

Comment: Yes, this is the only way to update permission param. If you updating status param, then we can ignore permission parameter like do_this(15, null, true)